# Print panel c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

how do I print a panel in C# winforms please.
it should be: there is a thumbnail in the application, but when I click the Print button, I want it to print on the entire A4 page (zoomed a little)

I get an exact copy of what I have in winforms

my code:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            
            System.Drawing.Bitmap MemoryImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(panel97.Width, panel97.Height);
            Rectangle pagearea = e.PageBounds;
            panel97.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, panel97.ClientRectangle);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, (pagearea.Width / 2) - (this.panel97.Width / 2), this.panel97.Location.Y);
            
        }

        private void btn_print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
            

            if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                printDocument1.Print();
                
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Printed", "");
            
        }
```

code working but, no whole A4.

thanks

Comment: A bit map is in pixels.  What is you height and width in pixels?

Comment: You can make it larger by setting the Dpi of the Bitmap to a lower value before printing, but the data will not be crisp as there is not enough information. For good results you need to write a real PrintPage code that creates the Panel on a page.

Comment: In `.DrawImage()`, you have to specify a source Rectangle and a destination Rectangle, not a Point

Comment: Can you give me a tip? Thank you